# Ansible - EC2 create new and remove tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I've more than 100 running instances

Example I have 10 running instances with tag name `dev-redis-slave`. And now I want to create new tag -> tag `ServiceName: redis-slave` and tag `ServiceGroup: redis`

First of all, I try following this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/getting-started-with-ansible-and-dynamic-amazon-ec2-inventory-management/

Then I try to excecute `ec2.py --list | grep redis`. Then the output is: `tag_Name_dev_redis_slave`. Also I try to ping: `ansible -m ping tag_Name_dev_redis_slave` and success.

Next I want to create new tag for `dev-redis-slave` using ansible.,
I create yaml file like this (playbook.yaml).

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Adding tags
    ec2_tag:
      resource: tag_Name_dev_redis_slave
      region: xxx
      state: present
      tags:
        ServiceGroup: redis
        ServiceName: redis-slave
```

I run `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml` But It give an error.

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: <Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidID</Code><Message>The ID 'tag_Name_dev_redis_slave' is not valid</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>de51df48-df26-4312-8d03-4c8ca2b993bf</RequestID></Response>
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/folders/5b/hhh0h2fx2cxf7_24dmn05ht00000gq/T/ansible_460t6taz/ansible_module_ec2_tag.py\", line 183, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/var/folders/5b/hhh0h2fx2cxf7_24dmn05ht00000gq/T/ansible_460t6taz/ansible_module_ec2_tag.py\", line 160, in main\n    ec2.create_tags(resource, dictadd)\n  File \"/Users/fourirakbar/Documents/ansible/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py\", line 4219, in create_tags\n    return self.get_status('CreateTags', params, verb='POST')\n  File \"/Users/fourirakbar/Documents/ansible/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py\", line 1227, in get_status\n    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)\nboto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidID</Code><Message>The ID 'tag_Name_dev_redis_slave' is not valid</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>de51df48-df26-4312-8d03-4c8ca2b993bf</RequestID></Response>\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
```

I also try to follow this: http://ansible-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ec2_tag_module.html#examples . But also error.

how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you post the real code you running, because the error message refers `tag_Name_development_jenkins_slave` which is not on playbook, please edit your question. Also please give version of ansible you use.

Comment: sry, I wrong copy paste the error. The correct one is `tag_Name_redis_slave`

Comment: are you sure `tag_Name_dev_redis_slave` is a valid resource that exit ? it seems you are messing up tag_Name_dev_redis_slave use for the ansible targets and this resource.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong to define `resource`. I think `resource=tag`, but the correct one is `resource=instance id`. Thankyou for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, I was wrong to define `resource`. I think `resource=tag`, but the correct one is `resource=instance id`. Thankyou for helping

so I change my `playbook.yaml` like this

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
    development:
      - YOUR INSTANCE ID
      - YOUR INSTANCE ID
  tasks:
  - name: Adding tags
    ec2_tag:
      resource: "{{ item }}"
      region: YOUR INSTANCE REGION
    args:
      tags:
        ServiceGroup: redis
        ServiceName: redis-slave
    with_items: "{{ development }}"
```

but I was wondering, maybe next I don't need to describe `instance id` one by one (imagine if we've so many instance with different group tag).

guys if you have an answer, please let me know

thank you very much